# Trying to use online banking for the 1st time using tor - what is this warning?

Tags: error

NoScript detected a potential Cross-Site Scripting attack

from https://www.sonabank.com to https://web13.secureinternetbank.com.

Suspicious data:

Cannot seem to proceed past this warning. Newbie to TOR and trying to go exclusively TOR for financials and legalities.

Comment: The NoScript extension has the ability to look at requests and see if they contain features common to cross-site scripting attacks. If you’re accessing a banking website (which will be encrypted with TLS), this is very likely a false-positive. As far as I know there should be a button to allow it. Do you see any buttons at all?

Comment: Yes I tried to use the "Allow" button but it kept defaulting back to the warning.

Comment: finally got through. took several attempts. Thanks.